# LRectangle with text in Vue leaflet

Tags: vue.js, leaflet

How can I put text in LRectangle in Vue leaflet?

I have alraedy tried:

```
    <l-rectangle
      :bounds="rectangle.bounds"
      :l-style="rectangle.style"
    >
      <span>DAWD</span>
    </l-rectangle>
```